# Suggest a better MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I am a relative noob when it comes to mysql queries so please don't bite my head off. I am trying to make a "Top Poller" module using a poll extension and Jomsocial. I want to display the top 5 users by the amount of polls they have created. Here is the data table structure (well the important parts)

```
#__users
-id
-name
-username

#_jcp_polls
-created_by (this is the same as #users.id)

#__community_users
-thumb
-avatar
```

Here is my query

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "SELECT u.id, u.username, u.name, c.thumb, c.avatar,COUNT(p.created_by) as total
      FROM #__users u, #__community_users c, #__jcp_polls p 
      WHERE u.id = p.created_by
      GROUP by u.id
  ORDER BY total DESC
      LIMIT $user_count
     ";

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I can display the user table fields in a foreach loop like

```
foreach($rows as $row){
 echo $row->name
}
```

I thought I would be able to use `$row->avatar` but it doesn't work. Can someone suggest a query that will allow me to display fields from the `#__community_users` table as well as the `#__users table`? and still keep the rankings from the `#__jcp_polls table`?

Answer (score 3):

Presently, you have no condition joining `#__community_users` to `#__users`. Here is an updated query with the implicit joins swapped out for explicit `INNER JOIN`s, assuming `#__community_users` has a column `user_id` which relates to `#__users.id`. In your table structure above, you have no column relating `#__community_users` to `#__users`. Without one, you cannot relate avatars to users.

```
SELECT 
  u.id, u.username, u.name, c.thumb, c.avatar,COUNT(p.created_by) as total
FROM 
  #__users u 
  /* Supply the correct column name for c.user_id */
  JOIN #__community_users c ON u.id = c.user_id
  /* LEFT JOIN used to list 0 for users who have no polls */
  LEFT JOIN #__jcp_polls p ON u.id = p.created_by
GROUP by u.id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT $user_count
```

If it is possible for a user not to have an avatar, use a `LEFT JOIN` against `#__community_users`:

```
SELECT 
  u.id, u.username, u.name, c.thumb, c.avatar,COUNT(p.created_by) as total
FROM 
  #__users u 
  /* Supply the correct column name for c.user_id */
  LEFT JOIN #__community_users c ON u.id = c.user_id
  /* LEFT JOIN used to list 0 for users who have no polls */
  LEFT JOIN #__jcp_polls p ON u.id = p.created_by
GROUP by u.id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT $user_count
```

Your syntax, although valid for MySQL, is not universally valid since you have multiple columns in the `SELECT` list but only `u.id` in the `GROUP BY`.  A more portable version of the query would look like:

```
SELECT
  u.id, u.username, u.name, c.thumb, c.avatar, p.total
FROM
  #__users u 
  LEFT JOIN #__community_users c ON u.id = c.user_id
  /* Left Join against a subquery that returns count per user */
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS total FROM #__jcp_polls GROUP BY created_by) p ON u.id = p.created_by
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT $user_count
```

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to explain. Looks great, im going to try it now